# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error when trying to modify a model which is solved using lazy constraint callback

Tags: cplex

I use CPLEX Consert Technology with C++ API. I am trying to modify a model after I solved it using lazy constraint callback. More precisely, I first solve the model using a lazy constraint callback, then add more constraints to the model, then try to solve the new model again using the same lazy constraint call back. Here is the code:

```
model.add ( Some_Constraints ) ;                    
cplex.extract(model) ;  
cplex.use( MyLazyCallback (env) );
if ( cplex.solve() )
{
    cout << endl << endl << cplex.getObjValue () << endl << endl ;      
}
else
{
    cout << endl << endl << cplex.getCplexStatus() << endl << endl ;                
}
model.add (More_Constraints) ;
cplex.extract(model) ;  
cplex.use( MyLazyCallback (env) ); // Not sure if we need this command again
if ( cplex.solve() )
{
    cout << endl << endl << cplex.getObjValue () << endl << endl ;      
}
else
{
    cout << endl << endl << cplex.getCplexStatus() << endl << endl ;                
}
```

The original model is solved with no errors, but the new model is not solved due to the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. The error comes from the second `cplex.extract(model) ;` command. Could you please helm me understand why this error occurs and how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

From the comments, I realized that there is something wrong with `MoreConstraints`. I create `MoreConstraints` in a loop and the contents of the loop is as follows:

```
IloRange RConstraint = SomeThing >= SomeValue ;
string RConstName = "RC" + to_string (Constraint_ID) ;
RConstraint.setName(RConstName.c_str()) ;

cout << "\n\n\nRconstraint " << RConstraint << endl ;       
MoreConstraints.add(RConstraint) ;
cout << "\n\n\nMoreConstraints " << MoreConstraints << endl ;
```

Here is the output of the above:

[image]

At each iteration, a new constraint is supposed to be added to `MoreConstraints`, but it does not.

Comment: Have you tried turning on the [datacheck](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/DataCheck.html) parameter? Have you tried running your code with valgrind? What happens if you replace `More_Constraints` with `Some_Constraints` (yes, you're just adding duplicates, but the point is to check if something about `More_Constraints` is the problem). By the way, you do not need to re-register the `MyLazyCallback`.

Comment: @rkersh Thanks. I activated datacheck but it shows nothing. The value of `MoreConstraints.getSize()` is 4 right before calling `model.add`. Is there anyway to see what is inside the `MoreConstraints`? Trying some other constraints it produces no errors which implies that there is something wrong with `MoreConstraints`.

Comment: What happens if you add `cout << "More_Constraints: " << More_Constraints << endl;` just before calling `extract`?

Comment: @rkersh I still get the same error, but this time from this new line. Debugging takes me to the following part of `iloextractable.h`:
`inline ILOSTD(ostream)& operator<<(ILOSTD(ostream)& out, const IloExtractable& ext) {
 if (ext.getImpl()) ext.getImpl()->display(out);
 return (out);
}`
The exception is thrown from this line: `if (ext.getImpl()) ext.getImpl()->display(out);`

Comment: @rkersh Please see the edit to the question.

Comment: We can see from your output, that every time you iterate through the loop you are overwriting the value of the previous constraints with the current constraint. So you are ending up with an array containing handles to the same constraint. Furthermore, when you exit the loop these handles are probably falling out of scope. I'd recommend that you study the C++ example programs that are included when you install CPLEX.

Comment: @rkersh Thanks rkersh. When not using lazy constraint callback, I apply the same approach to add cuts to a model without having problems. The new cut does not overwrite the previous one(s). The issue exists only when I use lazy constraint callback, that is, when the function that adds constraints is called from lazy constraint callback (when solving the original model).